# Laravel 5.1 File Download

Tags: laravel

I have  the following function for  paypal integration functionality in my laravel 5.1 application. the following function returns payment status after payment data is posted. what I need is to allow user to download files after payment is approved. How can I do that?

```
public function getPaymentStatus()
{
    // Get the payment ID before session clear
    $payment_id = Session::get('paypal_payment_id');

    $package_name = Session::get('package_name');
    $package_id = Session::get('$package_id');

    // clear the session payment ID
    Session::forget('paypal_payment_id');

    if (empty(Input::get('PayerID')) || empty(Input::get('token'))) {
        return Redirect::route('original.route')
            ->with('error', 'Payment failed');
    }

    $payment = Payment::get($payment_id, $this->_api_context);

    // PaymentExecution object includes information necessary
    // to execute a PayPal account payment.
    // The payer_id is added to the request query parameters
    // when the user is redirected from paypal back to your site
    $execution = new PaymentExecution();
    $execution->setPayerId(Input::get('PayerID'));

    //Execute the payment
    $result = $payment->execute($execution, $this->_api_context);

    // echo '<pre>';print_r($result);echo '</pre>';exit; // DEBUG RESULT, remove it later

    if ($result->getState() == 'approved') { // payment made

        //ToDo Release Later
        return Redirect::route('original.route')
            ->with('success', 'Payment success');

        // ToDo Release Later
        // $this->allow_download($package_id, $package_name);
    }

    return Redirect::route('original.route')
        ->with('error', 'Payment failed');
}
```

I want the user to get a link like this

```
< href="/packages/{{$package_id}}/{{$name}}">click here to download</a>.
```

Comment: Do you have DB for result payment?

Comment: Nop, Currently I don't want that. I just want to initiate download after payment is approved.

Comment: This is not done, do not you want to keep the date?You can do this, but it's not a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($result->getState() == 'approved') { // payment made

        //ToDo Release Later
        Session::set('approved', true);
        return Redirect::route('original.route')
            ->with('success', 'Payment success');

        // ToDo Release Later
        // $this->allow_download($package_id, $package_name);
    }
@if(Session::get('approved'))

    < href="/packages/{{$package_id}}/{{$name}}">click here to download</a>.

@endif
```

Comment: Better to use `Session::flash` otherwise everytime the user access the page it will see the link to download the file

Comment: but User Pay :) everytime pay?  This option is the worst, you need to save everything in DB

Comment: Yeah, i totally agree